# SQL Server CLR function aggregation of sorted string

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr, user-defined-aggregate

In order to get a sorted aggregated string, I wrote the CLR function below. However, it always returns empty instead of what I expected, just like "001, 002, 003". I tried to debug the CLR function in visual studio 2017, but threw the error message

> The operation could not be completed. Unspecified error

Code:

```
[Serializable]
[SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
    Format.UserDefined, //use clr serialization to serialize the intermediate result
    Name = "CLRSortedCssvAgg", //aggregate name on sql
    IsInvariantToNulls = true, //optimizer property
    IsInvariantToDuplicates = false, //optimizer property
    IsInvariantToOrder = false, //optimizer property
    IsNullIfEmpty = false, //optimizer property
    MaxByteSize = -1) //maximum size in bytes of persisted value
]

public class SortedCssvConcatenateAgg : IBinarySerialize
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The variable that holds all the strings to be aggregated.
    /// </summary>
    List<string> aggregationList;

    StringBuilder accumulator;

    /// <summary>
    /// Separator between concatenated values.
    /// </summary>
    const string CommaSpaceSeparator = ", ";

    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize the internal data structures.
    /// </summary>
    public void Init()
    {
        accumulator = new StringBuilder();
        aggregationList = new List<string>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Accumulate the next value, not if the value is null or empty.
    /// </summary>
    public void Accumulate(SqlString value)
    {
        if (value.IsNull || String.IsNullOrEmpty(value.Value))
        {
            return;
        }

        aggregationList.Add(value.Value);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Merge the partially computed aggregate with this aggregate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other"></param>
    public void Merge(SortedCssvConcatenateAgg other)
    {
        aggregationList.AddRange(other.aggregationList);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called at the end of aggregation, to return the results of the aggregation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public SqlString Terminate()
    {
        if (aggregationList != null && aggregationList.Count > 0)
        {
            aggregationList.Sort();
            accumulator.Append(string.Join(CommaSpaceSeparator, aggregationList));
            aggregationList.Clear();
        }

        return new SqlString(accumulator.ToString());
    }

    public void Read(BinaryReader r)
    {
        accumulator = new StringBuilder(r.ReadString());
    }

    public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
    {
        w.Write(accumulator.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the XML methods?

Comment: I can't help wondering if you are over complicating things using CLR?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Hey, Gordon. What do you mean by the XML methods?

Comment: See the chapter "The blackbox XML methods" in https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/

Comment: @JimmyWang . . . Google "SQL Server string aggregation".

Answer (score 2):

You are close. Just need a few minor adjustments. Do the following and it will work (I tested it):

1. Remove all references to `accumulator`. It is not used.
2. Replace the Terminate(), Read(), and Write() methods with the following:

   ```cs
   public SqlString Terminate()
   {
       string _Aggregation = null;

       if (aggregationList != null && aggregationList.Count > 0)
       {
           aggregationList.Sort();
           _Aggregation = string.Join(CommaSpaceSeparator, aggregationList);
       }

       return new SqlString(_Aggregation);
   }

   public void Read(BinaryReader r)
   {
       int _Count = r.ReadInt32();
       aggregationList = new List<string>(_Count);

       for (int _Index = 0; _Index < _Count; _Index++)
       {
           aggregationList.Add(r.ReadString());
       }
   }

   public void Write(BinaryWriter w)
   {
       w.Write(aggregationList.Count);
       foreach (string _Item in aggregationList)
       {
           w.Write(_Item);
       }
   }
   ```

---

That said, I'm not sure if this approach is faster or slower than the `FOR XML` approach, but a UDA certainly makes for a more readable query, especially if you need multiple aggregations.

Still, I should mention that starting in SQL Server 2017, this became a built-in function: [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql) (which allows for sorting via the `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ... )` clause).

Answer (score 0):

In your `Accumulate` and `Merge`, you're dealing with your `aggregationList`; in `Read` and `Write` you're dealing with `accumulator`. You should pick one or the other for all of them and use it. As I understand it, `Read` and `Write` are used when the engine needs to persist temporary results to a work table. For your case, when it does that, it's persisting only your empty StringBuilder.